# Can I request premium processing for an L-2 when I apply for premium processing on my L-1?

Tags: usa, family, l1-visa

USCIS [does not list L-2 as a visa that can be applied for with premium processing](https://www.uscis.gov/forms/how-do-i-use-premium-processing-service), but my petition has been submitted with premium processing.

Answer (score 3):

Premium processing is for the petition, not the visa.

Assuming your L-1 petition is accepted you next fill in your DS-160, you also fill DS-160 forms for each family member.  You then schedule a consular interview for all family members, giving the DS-160 for references for all the family.